# Multiple Gnosis-safe factory addresses on Base network and weird behavior during deployment of new safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

I deployed a safe on the Base network using the default proxy_factory address at `0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2`

Then I saw that the safe couldn't be loaded into the UI. At a deeper look, I see that the safe invoked the `ProxyCreation` method of the factory, and not the follow up `SafeSetup` method.
I manually invoked the SafeSetup (tx went through well) and now I have 3 questions:

1. How long will it take the UI indexer to recognize the safe so it can be present in the app?
2. Why for any other chain, deploying a safe shows in the logs both the creation as well as the setup, while for this, it stopped at the `ProxyCreation` and I needed to invoke the `SafeSetup` manually?
3. I recently saw that on the [proxy_factory list on github](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/blob/main/src/assets/v1.3.0/proxy_factory.json), the Base factory is at `0xC22834581EbC8527d974F8a1c97E1bEA4EF910BC` and not at `0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2`. Can I safely use the one I deployed via `0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I saw that the safe couldn't be loaded into the UI. At a deeper look, I see that the safe invoked the ProxyCreation method of the factory, and not the follow up SafeSetup method. I manually invoked the SafeSetup (tx went through well) and now I have 3 questions:

This is very strange, such a thing could only happen if the singleton wasn't deployed on-chain at the time of the deployment.

> How long will it take the UI indexer to recognize the safe so it can be present in the app?

The UI only works with the official deployments you referenced in the proxy factory list on GitHub. To use unofficial deployments, you can use safe cli tools: https://github.com/5afe/safe-cli or scripts.

> Can I safely use the one I deployed via 0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2?

Since the deployment is deterministic, the same address means the code is legit and hasn't changed. However, you use it at your own risk.